# How to Programmatically Delete Duplicate Records in a Tcl/Tk Treeview Widget

Tags: treeview, duplicates, tcl

I have a treeview widget in my Tcl/Tk application that will often show duplicate records.  I tried writing "lsort -unique" and "lrmdups" into my code to automatically delete the treeview duplicates, but with no luck.  If possible, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: A bit more detail would be helpful. There are several Tk tree widgets - which one exactly are you using?  Where does the data to populate it come from? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the ttk::treeview widget that is provided with Tk 8.5 and above then one way to ensure unique entries is to be careful about the -id parameter. It will automatically prevent duplicate items with the same id:

```
% pack [ttk::treeview .tv -columns {One Two}] -fill both -expand 1
% .tv insert {} end -id id1 -text First -values {1st first}
id1
% .tv insert {} end -id id1 -text Second -values {2nd second}
Item id1 already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of an item to delete, you can just do this:

```
.tv delete $id
```